# how to rename files in multiple folders numerically starting with '1' each folder using python?

Tags: python, count, rename, subdirectory, numeric

i'm trying to rename files numerically in multiple folders but it seems that the count continues to run through all the files and not starting from '1' each folder. what should i do?

i have tried the following code:

```
for folderName, subfolders, filenames in os.walk(path):
    for f in filenames:
        f_name, f_ext = os.path.splitext(f)
        f_name = str(count)
        count = count + 1

  new_name = '{}{}'.format(f_name, f_ext)          
  os.rename(os.path.join(folderName,f),os.path.join(folderName,new_name))


i expect the output renaming of the files to be:
files in folder 1: 1.tif, 2.tif, 3.tif, 4.tif 
files in folder 2: 1.tif, 2.tif, 3.tif
files in folder 3: 1.tif, 2.tif, 3.tif, 4.tif 

but the actual outcome is:
files in folder 1: 1.tif, 2.tif, 3.tif, 4.tif 
files in folder 2: 5.tif, 6.tif, 7.tif
files in folder 3: 8.tif, 9.tif, 10.tif, 11.tif
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
for folderName, subfolders, filenames in os.walk(path):
    count = 1   # << -- here are the changes
    for f in filenames:
        f_name, f_ext = os.path.splitext(f)
        f_name = str(count)
        count += 1
```